# Mathematica 8: Convert from cartesian to spherical coordinates

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, data-conversion

I just started using Mathematica and came across a problem. I would like to solve more elegantly. I have measurement data in `{x,y,z}` form and want to transform these into sperical coordinates. I know how to do it using simple functions. But the code gets ugly.
I would like something like:

```
v={x,y,z}
TranformSpherical[v]
```

I have looked in the documentation and only found something for version 9, I am using 8 and it did not work when I tried it. Also I have not found a clear solution anywhere else. Hope someone here knows a simple solution to the probem.

Comment: Please note that http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions is a much better place than this one for your Mathematca related questions

Answer (score 2):

The equations are [given on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates#Cartesian_coordinates) and are simple function evaluations. 
What's stopping you from simply computing them, and how does it get ugly?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Make sure to use `ArcTan[x, y]` in Mathematica, which computes the four-quadrant arctangent. For more information see the [article about atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Answer (score 2):

In version 9

```
CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", "Mapping", {x, y, z}]
```

gives you
    {Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2], ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]], ArcTan[x, y]}

which expresses the three spherical coordinates in terms of {x,y,z}

```
CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {x, y, z}]
```

will give you the same thing, but can also be used for conversion.
If you have a list {{x0,y0,z0},{x1,y1,z1},...} of Cartesian coordinates, you can apply CoordinateTransform like this

```
cartesianList = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 3}];

CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", #] & /@ cartesianList
```

In earlier versions

```
<< Calculus`VectorAnalysis`

SetCoordinates[Spherical]
```

There is a notebook at the mathworld.wolfram.com site page for Spherical Coordinates. Close to the beginning is an example for what you are doing.